# Querying PostgreSQL for Open-High-Low-Close (OHLC)

Tags: sql, postgresql

#### The structure stored in the data table is:

| id | code | price | created_at |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USDTBTC | 6.404203 | 1622781005 |
| 2 | USDTBTC | 6.404199 | 1622781065 |
| 3 | USDTBTC | 6.404202 | 1622781125 |

I hope to get `OHLC` data every 1 minute, 5 minutes,

```sql
select g,
       COALESCE(MAX(p.price), 0) AS high,
       COALESCE(MIN(p.price), 0) AS low
FROM generate_series(
                 date_trunc('minute', now() - '1 day'::interval),
                 date_trunc('minute', now()),
                 '5 minute'::interval
         ) as g
         LEFT JOIN product_trend p
                   ON p.code = 'USDCNY' AND to_char(concat(to_char(TO_TIMESTAMP(created_at), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI'), ':',
                                                           FLOOR(date_part('minute', TO_TIMESTAMP(created_at)) / 5) * 5):: timestamp,
                                                    'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI') =
                                            to_char(g, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI')
group by g
order by g;
```

I try to use `generate_series` because I am worried that there will be data gaps; but the data cannot be queried, how can I query?

Answer (score 0):

I am not actually sure what your real problem is, but I can see:

1. The code you are filtering on does not match the code in the data.
2. The date comparisons are very complex.  I can't tell if they are correct.
3. You are depending on `now()` which changes, literally, every second.

The following does "work" in the sense of returning the data from your table:

```
select g,
       COALESCE(MAX(p.price), 0) AS high,
       COALESCE(MIN(p.price), 0) AS low
FROM generate_series(date_trunc('minute', '2021-06-05'::date - interval '1 day'),
                     date_trunc('minute', '2021-06-05'::date),
                     interval '5 minute'
                     )  g LEFT JOIN
     product_trend p
     ON p.code = 'USDTBTC' AND
        p.created_at >= extract(epoch from g) and
        p.created_at < extract(epoch from (g + interval '5 minute'))
group by g
order by g;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a2964ad4e0fd971da4d440034e36a735) is a db<>fiddle.